# how to handle npm if accidentially deleted package.json file from the directory?

Tags: javascript, npm

[image]below image shows what is the error comming out while writting npm in command[image]

Comment: You can create package.json with `npm init -y`

Comment: @Vipulw its comming same again

Comment: Can you share your package.json

Comment: @Vipulw i have shared the active screenshot sorry for that but please help if your are able to